# Multisite: Retain awareness of what posts came from which site?

Tags: multisite

I'm pulling posts from two blogs, the main blog and the current blog. I've pulled all the posts into an array (`$hold`) so I can sort them all by date (rather than show all the posts from the main blog ordered by date, then followed by all the posts from the current blog sorted by date).

```
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE blog_id IN (1, 6)" );

if ( ! empty ( $blogs ) ) :
    // put all posts from each blog into $hold array
    $hold = array();

    // loop through each blog
    foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) :
        switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );
        $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'dt2',
            'posts_per_page' => 5
        );
        // get posts from each blog and add to $hold
        $q = new WP_query( $args );
        if ( $q->have_posts() ) :
            while( $q->have_posts() ) :
                $q->the_post();
                $hold[] = $post;
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_query();
        restore_current_blog();
    endforeach;

    // sort all posts from all blogs by post_date
    function sort_posts($a, $b)
    {
        return strtotime($b->post_date) - strtotime($a->post_date);
    }
    usort($hold, 'sort_posts');

    // iterate through all posts in $hold sorted newest to oldest
    global $post;
    foreach ( $hold as $i => $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post );
        get_template_part( 'content/post' );
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

When I get to the end and I'm going through the `$hold` array, I have problems. They seem to stem from the fact that we're not aware of which posts came from which blogs. So I have broken permalinks, missing featured images, etc. for any post that isn't being pulled from the current blog.

Is there a way to either add an indicator to the `$hold` array as I'm retrieving the contents of the post, or to otherwise determine what blog the post came from?

I'm very open to suggestions as to how to sort all posts by date, as I think that's what's leading me into this problem.

Comment: You would need to switch to blog, but keep in mind that switching and restoring is **expensive** and slow. Would it not be easier to display data via the REST API? Or pull the data via the frontend? Or syndicate the posts over so they exist as actual posts on this particular site? I also notice you embedded variables directly into your query string without using `prepare`, and that you used a raw query instead of `get_sites()`. I would also replace the `wp_reset_query` with `wp_reset_postdata`, `wp_reset_query` is for cleaning up after a call to `query_posts`, `WP_query` needs to be `WP_Query`

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas and suggestions, I'm new to tinkering with multisite. What do you mean when you say "pull the data via the frontend"?

Comment: Request it with javascript and construct the list in the browser client-side. It even has the upside that in the future you could filter and sort the data. There's a REST API that you can use to list posts already so you don't have to build anything on the PHP side to get ajax working, just make a request to `yoursiite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` and you'll get a nice JS object back with all the info you asked for